# In Outlook, how to get a prompt when you've been added to a meeting or when a meetings time has changed?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, prompt, meetings

I've had a few bad experiences where I missed a meeting because it was scheduled during the day and I was not at my computer when the outlook 15 minute prior to meeting prompt was displayed.

I usually check in the morning to see if I have any meetings for the day but sometimes a meeting is created after I've checked. I try to check each time before I go AFK, but there are times I'm in the middle of a thought and I forget to check before heading off to my whiteboard.

Is there a way for outlook to prompt me when a meeting I've accepted has been updated or when I get invited to a meeting?

Currently I only get a prompt 15 minutes prior to the meetings start time.

Comment: 1. If Outlook changes a meeting, normally you will be requested to update (no response) or accept again (response).  2. Use a smart phone that you carry with you to keep track of changes.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, when others invite us to attend a meeting or update a meeting, we will receive a invitation email or an update email by default. If you don't pay attention to or receive this invitation email, please check and disable the option of automatically processing meeting requests, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

If you still feel that the email is not obvious enough, it is recommended that you try to create a rule to display desktop alerts for incoming meeting requests or update(File > Info > Manage Rules & Alerts > New Rule).

[image]

In addition, we can also set the default reminder so that you can be reminded before the meeting starts via File>Options>Calendar>Calendar Options.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.